# What is the <number>! in byobu's status bar mean?

Tags: server, byobu

I run `byobu` on my home server, and I noticed this today - what is it?

It's part of the byobu notification/status bar, on a 64-bit 11.10 server.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/byobu):

> **updates_available** - the number of updates available on the system; displayed in the lower bar toward the right in white text on a red background with a trailing '!' sign; if any updates are marked 'security updates', then there will be a total of two trailing exclamation points, '!!'

Comment: Is there any way to tell what these updates are? I am using byobu on a mac (installed with brew) and all brew packages are up to date. It's driving me bonkers ... the 1! since I can't tell what it is!!!

Comment: @AhiTuna [check for `apt-check`](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/master/usr/lib/byobu/updates_available#L51): `python3 /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable`.

Answer (score 19):

This shows the number of packages that need to be updated on the system.