# How to determine if installing updates will require a reboot?

Tags: server, updates, package-management, reboot

I have some Ubuntu Server machines which I'd like to keep up-to-date, but not always if it requires a reboot.

Is there a way to tell if pending package updates require a reboot BEFORE installing the packages?

Comment: Related: [How can I tell, from the command line, whether the machine requires a reboot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164/how-can-i-tell-from-the-command-line-whether-the-machine-requires-a-reboot?rq=1)