# How to check if installing a package will require a reboot?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, reboot

I often install packages and updates for them, although sometimes it is not convenient to do a reboot if one of the packages needs it, so is there any way of telling **BEFORE** installing the package/update whether or not it will require you to do a reboot? I have already looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/276640/364819) and the solutions there don't solve my problem, nor the more or less same one described there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no flag of sorts on packages that indicate that a reboot is required if the package is installed or updated. So, short answer: you can't.

However, you could extract the .deb files of the package before installing or updating to see if a reboot notification is made in the `DEBIAN/postinst` script. For example, the `postinst` script in the `linux-image-*.deb` packages execute the `/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required` script, which in turn creates the `/var/run/reboot-required` file. Other `postinst` scripts may use the same method to indicate a necessary reboot, but there's no enforcement of a default method of getting to the creation of the `/var/run/reboot-required` file. It might be that a package is maintained by someone who isn't really into doing things like other maintainers do, and decides that the reboot notification can also be done in another script, like `DEBIAN/preinst`. So, long answer: you can, but it'll be a real nightmare to implement and maintain a way to detect all possible reboot notifications.