# Which package update(s) triggered the 'Server reboot required' message?

Tags: server, apt, package-management, updates

After updating a number of packages, I get the 'Server reboot required' message upon login. What specific package or package(s) triggered this message?

Note: Two other questions address *why* a reboot is required for some updates e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36710/why-is-a-restart-only-required-on-some-updates) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741375/why-is-server-restart-required), but my question is specifically asking how to identify the package(s) that triggered this. It's also worth linking to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674967/how-to-check-if-installing-a-package-will-require-a-reboot) related question that asks how to identify the packages that would require a restart before performing the update

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to identify this info is to look in `/var/run` at these files

```
$ cat /var/run/reboot-required
*** System restart required ***
$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
linux-base
linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic
```

These files will not exist unless a reboot is required, so checking if they exist is also a nice trick to know if a reboot is required:

```
[ -e /var/run/reboot-required* ] && echo "Reboot is required!" || echo "Reboot is not required."
```