# How to determine if a restart is needed on my Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, updates, reboot

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04. Whenever I login it will tell me if I have updates which is great, I will run those updates and go about my business. The next time I login, it tells me that the server needs a restart.

My question is, besides logging out and logging back in, is there a way to tell if the machine needs a reboot?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check this answer to a previous and very similar question:

[How can I tell, from the command line, whether the machine requires a reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164/how-can-i-tell-from-the-command-line-whether-the-machine-requires-a-reboot)

In essence, you just need to check if this file has been created after updates, configuration changes or security updates:  **/var/run/reboot-required**.
If you need to check which installed packages need the reboot then open the file /var/run/reboot-required.dpkgs

Comment: Suggestion - if the above file name of which packages produced the reboot notice doesn't work for an installation, try changing the file name extension from .dpkgs to .pkgs (drop the 'd')