# Ubuntu 14.04 virtual server security updates - no reboot necessary?

Tags: server, apt, updates

I have purchased a virtual server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My provider told me that I'm responsible for keeping the virtual server up to date. Precisely, I was told to run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

from time to time to get all important security updates. So this is what I'm doing but I'm still wondering: will this really get me all important security fixes?

Being a Windows user, I'd expect the system to reboot after important system updates. When I run the line shown above, however, the system never reboots but just continues running so I'm wondering if the line above is really enough to get all important security updates or do I have to do anything else?

Maybe Ubuntu is capable of installing security updates without rebooting but from Windows (and Mac OS, and Android, and iOS) I'm used to reboots after important security updates and it makes me a little worried that Ubuntu never wants to reboot after running the line above.

So I'd be glad if somebody could just confirm (or not!) whether the line shown above is really enough to keep the system up to date, securitywise.

Comment: Related: [How can I tell, from the command line, whether the machine requires a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164/how-can-i-tell-from-the-command-line-whether-the-machine-requires-a-reboot)